# Bootstrap with another css

Tags: html, css

[You will have to download my css.](https://ufile.io/3vpks)

So my problem is that when I integrate a CSS I got from a Theme with Bootstrap they don't work correctly in some things.

For example in the NavBar Tabs I get this: https://i.gyazo.com/efc844a5a93e14bf602d4983df7e8961.png

How ***can I know what's causing this?***

**It should look like this:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <h1>Ipsum</h1>
        <div role="tabpanel">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills brand-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="brand-nav active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="brand-nav"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Zombie ipsum</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="brand-nav"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Gansta ipsum</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="brand-nav"><a href="#tab4" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Corporate ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tincidunt feugiat lorem, at ornare tellus faucibus ut.
                            Curabitur eget metus dapibus nibh laoreet lacinia eget id metus. Mauris quis convallis elit, ac convallis augue. 
                            Pellentesque ornare cursus nibh quis fermentum. Morbi faucibus at tortor sed volutpat. Etiam at ex molestie turpis aliquam auctor.
                            Nulla consequat tristique augue, vel venenatis massa fringilla sit amet. Morbi egestas turpis facilisis sem faucibus finibus.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Nam sodales magna eget nulla interdum gravida. Aenean cursus magna vel lorem eleifend, vel eleifend massa rhoncus. 
                            Duis accumsan vehicula ultricies. Proin tincidunt blandit congue. Curabitur semper odio ut malesuada dapibus.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                        <p>
                            Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. 
                            Summus brains sit, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris.
                            Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium.
                            Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere 
                            carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. 
                            Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsizzle dolor away amizzle, consectetuer pizzle elizzle. Nullizzle yo velizzle, check it out volutpizzle, quis, gravida vel, yo.
                            Ma nizzle eget tortor. Sizzle eros. My shizz izzle dolizzle gizzle turpis tempizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle.
                            Maurizzle pellentesque nibh izzle own yo'. Check it out in tortor. Pellentesque fizzle rhoncizzle nisi. 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Shizzlin dizzle dapibus. You son of a bizzle tellizzle urna, pretizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle,
                            ghetto ac, check it out vitae, nunc. Shizzlin dizzle suscipizzle. Integizzle sempizzle velit sizzle dizzle.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                        <p>
                            Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. 
                            Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without 
                            revolutionary ROI.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. 
                            Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar 
                            solutions without functional solutions.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Completely synergize resource sucking relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate 
                            one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service 
                            for state of the art customer service.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: So you want us to 1.) download your CSS from a "Third party website". 2.) Check your CSS and Bootstrap 3.) Imagine what is going wrong with your result by viewing the image and 4.) Give you the answer. Don't you think you are asking too much.??

Comment: Please read these: [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Custom CSS file display of your nav class is set to `display:flex` on line 2561. as below...

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

remove this property and change that code like below, it will be fine.

```
.nav {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
```

Comment: how did you find this? Do you know a better tool than chrome?

Comment: **wow thanks man that was great help it worked. ;)**

Comment: nop, chrome dev tools inspect element is best one for html or css.